# How to remove nginx and re activate apache?

Tags: server, nginx, software-uninstall

I have installed `Apache2, mysql, php5 and phpmyadmin` on my Ubuntu 14.04 but later on mistakenly I install nginx.

Now my localhost page show me *Welcome to nginx server*. And the `localhost/phpmyadmin` link is not working.

How can I get my LAMP server back?

i removed ngnix using command

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx
sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

installing apache

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

but at the end on restarting apache2 i get this error

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'restart' failed.
```

Comment: How did you install nginx? With `apt-get`?

Comment: yes i believe so

Comment: I will add something to keep in mind here.  `/var/www/` and `/var/www/html` tend to be the 'default' docroot for web servers; if NGINX was installed before Apache it's entirely possible the 'default index page' that is installed by the web server is still present, and the system does NOT overwrite that when installing Apache or NGINX (in case the user actually has a custom page there).  That may be why 'nginx' landing pages were being seen instead of Apache, so you should always check to make sure either no index.html is present or a custom one you wrote is present.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you need to stop `nginx` so it releases port 80 so that `apache2` can listen to it later on.

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Next, if `nginx` was installed with `apt-get`, it can be removed by running one of the following two commands *(I explained the difference in the next paragraph)*.

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

Both of them remove all package files, while the second also removes the configuration files that package had installed.
*If you intend to use `nginx` later on with the configuration you did, use `remove`. Else, I would suggest using `purge`.*

After removing `nginx`, you can restart `apache` to make sure it is listening to port 80.

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

If you had removed `apache` before installing `nginx`, you can re-install it with

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: hi thankx for help i tried those two commands to remove nginx even though on localhost ot show nginx success page. not even/phpmyadmin workin

Comment: question edited please have a look

Answer (score 12):

if after that the Welcome to nginx! page appears you can try unistall other version on nginx existing on your server with

`sudo apt-get remove nginx-*`

and

`sudo apt-get purge nginx-*`

Comment: This is the solution in addition to `sudo apt-get remove nginx`.

Comment: I still see Welcome page...

Answer (score 2):

Remove all nginx packages

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nginx
sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

This works for me

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Deepin, I had to do more than

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx-*
```

the execution of the

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

When I finished, I realized that

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

that the apache had also been removed.
I reinstalled with the command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

And I restarted the service with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```