# my localhost default page welcome me on nginx

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp, nginx

I am again getting frustrated by my nginx server. I am trying to install `laravel` in my `/var/www/project` folder but when i delete the default HTML dir from `/var/www/html` it deviates me to the `nginx` welcome page. phpmyadmin doesn't work either.

How can I get Apache back and also remove nginx permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the Step to switch nginx to apache2

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx
sudo apt-get purge nginx
sudo apt-get remove nginx-common
sudo apt-get purge nginx-common
sudo apt-get remove nginx-full
sudo apt-get purge nginx-full
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After removing nginx make sure your nginx remove completely. by running this command.

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep nginx
```

If you get any pacakges related with nginx, remove them.

Now Install apache2 on your Ubuntu and all your services related with your projects.

```
 sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

First autoclean n autoremove unnecessary files
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get autoremove

Re install apache2 and check

Comment: I removed nginx, and followed all the process as in http://askubuntu.com/questions/470737/how-to-remove-nginx-and-re-activate-apache  , but i didn’t succeed in removing nginx and regain apache and phpmyadmin back.