# How to replace nginx with apache Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, nginx

I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.

I am now setting up my LAMP stack using [this guide](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2014/06/how-to-install-lamp-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts.html), and on starting apache2 I'm getting some errors:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

$ sudo netstat -lnpt
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:80 LISTEN 21254/nginx
```

Aha! So Nginx is the culprit! After some searching, I find [in this blog post](https://anturis.com/blog/nginx-vs-apache/) that Nginx is a new server, providing the same functionality (more or less?) as Apache. It must have come packaged with Ubuntu 14.04(?). I am a very new web-dev in training, and just want Apache for running Ruby on Rails apps etc.

**I now want to replace Nginx with Apache.**

I found and tried the answers to
[How to remove nginx and re activate apache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470737/how-to-remove-nginx-and-re-activate-apache) and
[Cannot remove NGINX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457040/cannot-remove-nginx)

but all commands result in

```
Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed
```

**Can anyone help me totally remove Nginx so I can get Apache working?**

Comment: nginx does not come packaged with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: hmm - maybe it installed with GitLab... when I go to localhost:80, GitLab shows up!

Comment: @PeterJacobson Yes, nginx is part of the Gitlab omnibus package. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I followed the instructions in a forum (sorry, lost the url) for running apache2 WITH Nginx.

I changed the apache listening ports from 80 to 81 in

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

and

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Apache2 is now working, tested by typing localhost:81 into the browser! Woohoo!

Comment: Does that means your problem is solved ?