# apache2 server is not starting

Tags: networking, server, apache2

every time i start server it gives this error...

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-12-24 23:55:49 IST; 10ms ago
  Process: 11423 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2154 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 24 23:55:49 shantanu apachectl[11423]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2401:4900:30e5:3307:2136:8a60:4eeb:ba13. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Dec 24 23:55:49 shantanu apachectl[11423]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Dec 24 23:55:49 shantanu apachectl[11423]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Dec 24 23:55:49 shantanu apachectl[11423]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Dec 24 23:55:49 shantanu apachectl[11423]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Dec 24 23:55:49 shantanu apachectl[11423]: Action 'start' failed.
Dec 24 23:55:49 shantanu apachectl[11423]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 24 23:55:49 shantanu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

OUTPUT OF : sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14946/unicorn maste 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7251/nginx: worker  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3354/sidekiq 5.2.7  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7251/nginx: worker
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question by adding output of command `sudo netstat -aptun| grep ':80 '`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Done

Comment: As you see there is an ngnix server running on this port. If you are not using it, stop it or even (better) remove it, before start using Apache web server. Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/470737/how-to-remove-nginx-and-re-activate-apache

Comment: Thanks @FedonKadifeli for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve this problem  i perform some commands :**

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

---

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23306/unicorn maste 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23331/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3354/sidekiq 5.2.7  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23331/nginx: master
```

Then search the program according pid :

```
sudo pwdx 23331
```

---

```
23331: /var/opt/gitlab/nginx
```

**Then i found gitlab program it have internal nginx service** so i stop them gitlab program

```
sudo gitlab-ctl stop
```